# Java OpenGL screen sized texture mapped quad

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, texture2d

I have a Java OpenGL (JOGL) app, and I'm trying to create a texture mapped quad that covers the entire screen. In draw some pixels to a buffer and then I want to read those pixels into a texture and redraw them on screen (with a fragment shader applied). My code for mapping the texture to the viewport is:

```
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);                                        
        gl.glPushMatrix();                                                 
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                                               
        gl.glOrtho( 0, width, height, 0, -1, 1 );                          
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);                                  
        gl.glPushMatrix();                                                 
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, ib);
        gl.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        //buff contains pixels read from glReadPixels
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buff);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ib.get(0));
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        gl.glVertex2f(0,0); 
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        gl.glVertex2f(0,height);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1,0);   
        gl.glVertex2f(width,height);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1,1);      
        gl.glVertex2f(width,0);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPopMatrix();
```

The end result is a quad that is not covering the whole viewport (it's partially on) and that does not contain the pixels from the buffer. What am I doing incorrectly here?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You should also keep in mind, that flipping your screen vertically (in your `glOrtho` call) effectively reverses the orientation of your faces. But since you see at least something, that won't be your problem, as with culling you wouldn't see anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should only create the texture in your initialization code. You should not be calling glTexImage2D every frame. Only call glTexImage2D again if the size of the texture changes; glTexSubImage2D can be used to upload data to the texture. Think of glTexImage2D as "new", while glTexSubImage2D as a memory copy.

Do this once, after initializing OpenGL.

```
IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);  //Store this in your object
gl.glGenTextures(1, ib);
gl.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
//buff contains pixels read from glReadPixels
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ib.get(0));
gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Then, each frame, do this:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);                                        
gl.glPushMatrix();                                                 
gl.glLoadIdentity();                                               
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);                                  
gl.glPushMatrix();                                                 
gl.glLoadIdentity();

gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ib.get(0));  //Retrieved from your object
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buff);

gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    gl.glVertex2f(-1, -1); 
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   
    gl.glVertex2f(1, 1);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);      
    gl.glVertex2f(1, -1);
gl.glEnd();

gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);                                  
gl.glPopMatrix();   
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);                                        
gl.glPopMatrix();   
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

By using identity for projection and modelview, we are able to supply vertex coordinates directly in clip-space. The [-1, 1] range in clip-space maps to [0, width/height] in window space. So we don't have to know or care about how big the window is; as long as the glViewport was set up correctly, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the problem, but it won't be helping: You are popping the modelview matrix twice for a single push. You are not popping the projection matrix at all.

I would recommend setting the projection matrix once at startup, without doing any pushes or pops. You don't really need to push and pop the modelview matrix either. (You could do your texture setup once at startup, too.)

Comment: it was not the problem, but those are still good suggestions and corrections, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking glError with code like the below. Note I used the GL2 object because there were some issues with older versions of JOGL and the GL object, silly things like GL_QUADS not being there.

If you have a shader enabled with the above code, you need to do the texturing by reading the sampler. If so, please attach the shader code you are using with this rendering code.

```
private static void checkForGLErrors(GL2 gl) {
    int errno = gl.glGetError();
    switch (errno) {
        case GL2.GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Invalid ENUM");
            break;
        case GL2.GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Invalid Value");
            break;
        case GL2.GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Invalid Operation");
            break;
        case GL2.GL_STACK_OVERFLOW:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Stack Overflow");
            break;
        case GL2.GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Stack Underflow");
            break;
        case GL2.GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            System.err.println("OpenGL Error: Out of Memory");
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

I would also try to avoid generating the texture every frame if it is something that doesn't change. You can save the textureId and bind it later.

Comment: The GL error code is returning 0, so no errors at this point.